# Reshaping data in Pandas (multi index in the columns, maybe in the rows too)

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a dataframe with 6 columns.  The first 5 uniquely identify an observation.  The 6th is the value of that observation.  I would like to pivot the data so that, of the 5 identifying columns, 3 become a hierarchical row index while the other 2 become a hierarchical column index.

Specifically, with the following setup:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

np.random.seed(1)

team_names = ['Yankees', 'Mets', 'Dodgers']
jersey_numbers = [35, 71, 84]
game_numbers = [1, 2]
observer_names = ['Bill', 'John']
observation_types = ['Speed', 'Strength']

row_indices = list(product(team_names, jersey_numbers, game_numbers, observer_names, observation_types))
observation_values = np.random.randn(len(row_indices))

tns, jns, gns, ons, ots = zip(*row_indices)

data = pd.DataFrame({'team': tns, 'jersey': jns, 'game': gns, 'observer': ons, 'obstype': ots, 'value': observation_values})
```

I would like to reshape the data so that the rows are `team`, `jersey`, and `game` while the columns are `observer` and `obstype`.  The following seems to get the job done:

```
pd.pivot_table(data, values='value', cols=['observer', 'obstype'], rows=['team', 'jersey', 'game'])
```

Are there any other ways to do this kind of thing?  I had initially tried making all the columns except for `value` into an index and then using `unstack(['observer', 'obstype'])`.  But this gave me an unnecessary extra level in my column hierarchy: an unnamed level whose only entry was `value` (i.e. the name of the column whose data I actually wanted in the guts of my table).

What's the right way to handle a situation like this?  Is it just to use `pivot_table` as I did above?  Or is there a better general strategy?

Comment: Both sound right to me. Can't get better than a one-liner, except that long lines are a pain to read ([PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): *Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters.*)

Comment: If I go with the "make a huge index, then unstack" method how do I kill the extra level in the column hierarchy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also think both are good and valuable options.
And in the case of `unstack` to get rid of the extra level, you can use `droplevel`:

```
>>> data = data.unstack(['observer', 'obstype'])
>>> data.columns = data.columns.droplevel(0)
>>> data
observer                 Bill                John          
obstype                 Speed  Strength     Speed  Strength
game jersey team                                           
1    35     Dodgers -0.110447 -0.617362  0.562761  0.240737
            Mets    -0.517094 -0.997027  0.248799 -0.296641
            Yankees  0.520576 -1.144341  0.801861  0.046567
     71     Dodgers  1.904659  1.111057  0.659050 -1.627438
            Mets     2.190700 -1.896361 -0.646917  0.901487
            Yankees  0.529465  0.137701  0.077821  0.618380
     84     Dodgers -0.400878  0.824006 -0.562305  1.954878
            Mets     1.331457 -0.287308  0.680070 -0.319802
            Yankees  1.038825  2.186980  0.441364 -0.100155
2    35     Dodgers  0.280665 -0.073113  1.160339  0.369493
            Mets     0.495211 -0.174703  0.986335  0.213534
            Yankees -0.186570 -0.101746  0.868886  0.750412
     71     Dodgers  0.602319  0.420282  0.810952  1.044442
            Mets     2.528326 -0.248635  0.043669 -0.226314
            Yankees  0.232495  0.682551 -0.310117 -2.434838
     84     Dodgers -1.331952 -1.760689 -1.650721 -0.890556
            Mets    -1.272559  0.313548  0.503185  1.293226
            Yankees -0.136445 -0.119054  0.017409 -1.122019

[18 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: This is going to be the silliest question of the day: How do you paste a data frame into a StackOverflow response so cleanly?  I am using iPython Notebook, but am open to using other tools just to get that done as nicely as you did above.

Comment: Not a silly question! Because indeed, when you copy it out of a notebook (the nice html table), it doesn't look that good. Your way of pasting it like a picture looks nice, but I suppose a little bit cumbersome. I often go to a plain terminal when I answer questions here, so I can copy paste it easily. Or in a notebook, you can also do `print df.to_string()` and you will get the same plain text repr instead of the html table.